# Allowing only integers and value should be between 1 and 100

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a text box which has to accept only integers on keypress. I achieved this using keycode through

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  dojo.stopEvent(evt);
}
```

Now, on keypress I have to restrict the entered value from range 1 to 100(including 100) and should allow backspace character to enable user to delete numbers.I have to implement in native javascript or dojo library. Is there any way to achieve both?

Comment: Don't use charCode. Read the value and test that, otherwise you will exclude all sorts of valid keystrokes like backspace, cursor key presses, etc. Also, users can paste anything into the control and you won't get a key code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying what the user enters is really annoying, much better to give them on screen hints about formatting required and validate the value when it's sent to the server (or whatever you are doing with it).

But if you *really* want to do this anyway, don't test the key pressed, test the actual value in the control:

```
<input ... onkeyup="checkValue(this.value);">
```

and the function:

```
function checkValue(s) {

  // use a regular expression to test the value is only digits
  var re = /^\d+$/;

  if (re.test(s) && s > 0 && s < 100) {
    // do success stuff

  } else {
    // do failed stuff
  } 
}
```

Now the same function can be used while the user is typing and also when the value is sent to the server. If you must use keyCode for this assignment, then you'll need to allow lots of codes other than just numbers (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at dojo's [Number Text Box](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.html)? It sounds like exactly what you want, and you can constrain the range of the contents.